# Smarty viewport if statement

Tags: css, smarty, viewport

Is there any way to display content based on the users viewport size using a Smarty "if" statement? For example I am creating a form, and if the user is on a small device (320px) then I would like the label to be the form's initial input value (ie. Your Name) which is cleared on blur/focus, and if the user is viewing on a desktop then I would like the labels displayed to the left of the input field.

Comment: FYI, that: _“if the user is on a small device (320px) then I would like the label to be the form's initial input value (ie. Your Name) which is cleared on blur/focus, and if the user is viewing on a desktop then I would like the labels displayed to the left of the input field”_ does not necessarily need different HTML code to be rendered, but (depending on specifics) could probably be achieved using only CSS as well. See https://css-tricks.com/float-labels-css/ (for the placeholder part; different display on large screens would be accomplished via media queries.)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this with PHP and it wouldn't be possible with Smarty templates. The best you could do with PHP is get the user agent and if it's a mobile user agent then do what you want.

You could download a mobile detect class like this one, http://mobiledetect.net/, and then create a Smarty variable that would be available in your template.

Answer (score 0):

that sort of logic should be done on the client via css media queries.  You can render the labels, but hide them on larger screens.

```
<style>
@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .myLabels {
    display: none;
  }
}
</style>

<label class="myLabels">Your name</label>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_querieshi